# Rebase/Redux/Firebase + React data not piping in

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, firebase-realtime-database, rebase

Trying to get a table of data from Firebase 3.x.x to sync with my React app. As far as I'm aware this is the most popular library for syncing the two states. Brackets are filled in with appropriate data.

App.js:

```
componentDidMount() {

 var base = Rebase.createClass({
   apiKey: "[API Key]",
   authDomain: "[app-name].firebaseapp.com",
   databaseURL: "https://[my-app].firebaseio.com",
   storageBucket: "[app-name].appspot.com",
 })
 base.syncState(`records`, {
       context: this,
       state: 'records',
       asArray: true
     })
}
```

when I call

```
console.log(this.props.state.records)
```

I get an empty array (the one that was initialized in state.js)
My data in firebase looks like this:

https://[app-name].firebaseio.com/ :

```
[app-name]{
  records[
    record_1{
     id: 0
     description: "this is a record"
    }
    record_2{
     id: 1
     description: "this is another record"
    }
  ]
}
```

Edit: I dont think it has to do with authentication. Setting read and write to true in database.rules.sjon didn't produce any results.

Edit: Firebase is showing bandwidth usage.

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be `console.log(this.state.records)` instead ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

So the data was actually getting there to begin with. I was originally querying it inside the render() method. When I made a button that fired a class method that queried this.state.records, the data showed up.

So that means **state is not initialized until the JSX return block inside the render method**. Seems a little odd but hey, now I know.